# Read node within namepace Simplexml

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I have the following xml code:

File 1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <DataSet xmlns="">
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
   <dsAanbod>
    <Pand diffgr:id="Pand1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
      <PandID>231384</PandID>
    </Pand>
   </dsAanbod>
 </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

How can i read the data between

I had the following php code

```
<?php 


    $xml_url = "1.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);

    foreach ($xml as $entry){

       //Use that namespace
       $namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
       //Now we don't have the URL hard-coded
       $diffgr = $entry->children($namespaces['diffgr']); 
       echo $diffgr->diffgram->dsAanbod->Pand->PandID;
}


?>
```

But that doesn't work.

Can somebody help me to get acces to a node where it is a child of an namespace element.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

Oh, where to begin. This working code might illustrate some of the problems:

```
<?php
    $xml_url = "1.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);
    foreach($xml->children('diffgr',true) as $diffgr){
            $weirdemptynamespace = $diffgr->children('',true);
            echo $weirdemptynamespace->dsAanbod->Pand->PandID;
   }
```

To name a few problems:

1. `xmlns=""` is NOT the same as no namespace, and, in my opinion, just.... well, weird.
2. Your `foreach` was premature (`children('diffgr')` should be called on the root element (`Dataset`).
3. If you are only interested in the namespace-prefix, just set the 2nd argument of `children()` to `true`.

Comment: Hehe, in a way I'm glad there is one less  `xmlns=""` out there then I thought ;) `foreach($weirdemptynamespace->dsAanbod->Pand as $kot){echo $kot->PandID;}` should do the trick?